# How do I scale a group in Phaser 3

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, phaser-framework

In Phaser 2 we scale a simple by setting the scale property as explained in docs:

https://phaser.io/examples/v2/groups/group-scale

But there is no equivalent in Phaser v3.

The possible url https://phaser.io/examples/v3/groups/group-scale points to nothing. And if I do:

```
this.enemies = this.add.group();
this.enemies.scale.set(2, 2);
```

It throws:

```
 Phaser v3.19.0 (WebGL | Web Audio)  https://phaser.io
indexph.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

What is the appropriate form to scale a group of sprites in Phaser 3?

The code below should work, I think, But it doesn't.... it doesn't scale  objects that are created from the group:

```
preload() {
    this.load.atlas("sprites", "assets/spritesheet.png", "assets/spritesheet.json")
}

create() {


    this.enemies = this.add.group({
        key: 'sprites' ,                        
        setScale: { x: 0.1, y: 0.1 }
    });

    this.enemies.create(60, 60, 'sprites', 'hamburguer.png');
```

Answer (score 3):

In Phaser 3, you can scale a group by modifying the GroupConfig object passed in when you declare your group.

GroupConfig [API Reference](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.GameObjects.Group.html#.GroupConfig). You can see also see a live demo [here](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cgame%20objects%5Cgroup%5Cset%20scale.js).

In your case, to scale this group you should simply create it like:

```
this.enemies = this.add.group({
  setScale: { x: 2, y: 2}
});
```

Alternatively, you could iterate through the group once it's created and scale each child object independently.

```
this.enemies = this.add.group();
this.enemies.children.iterate((child) => {
  child.setScale(2, 2);
});
```

Comment: the first snipped doesn't work on my code. I don't know why. I updated the question to show how I created the objects.

Comment: I should definitely use the iterator in js because the code looks more stylish :D

Comment: to go ahead on your approach and the update of your question, if it doesn't work maybe it's because you don't add the gameobject but you use the key to add it to the group ? https://jsfiddle.net/nazimboudeffa/m3649ydn/

Comment: Ah, my bad -- the first snippet only applies when you're also creating all of the child objects in the group config. If you want to create each group object independently, the second snippet is what you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade'
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
  this.load.image('alien1', 'sprites/phaser-alien.png');
  this.load.image('alien2', 'sprites/alien2.png');
}

function create ()
{ 
  this.enemies1 = this.add.group();
  this.enemies2 = this.add.group();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++)
  {
    let x = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 400);
    let y = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 600);

    this.enemy1 = this.add.image(x, y, 'alien1');
    this.enemies1.add(this.enemy1);
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++)
  {
    let x = Phaser.Math.Between(400, 800);
    let y = Phaser.Math.Between(0, 600);

    this.enemy2 = this.add.image(x, y, 'alien2');
    this.enemies2.add(this.enemy2);
  }
  
  console.log(this.enemies1.getLength())
  //console.log(this.enemies.getChildren())
  console.log(this.enemies1.getChildren()[2])
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++)
  { 
    this.enemies1.getChildren()[i].setScale(2);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.19.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would like to set the scale direct in the group

Comment: I think it's not correct to scale group the way I trying. I read some place that groups are not visual object, so it's not make sense to do these things with them..

Comment: I have just answered in a simple way that one can have in mind, by iterating on the group children, sure there is another way to do it but this way it looks clean for someone new to phaser